# Differences in fonts and location markers in Google Maps Styling Wizard vs JavaScript API output

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've searched through the Google Maps JavaScript API documentation and I can't seem to find the appropriate options to make my map's labels and location markers look like this:
[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

I realize the differences are subtle but it's what my client wants.

Using the Google Maps Styling Wizard, the styles on the top image appear to be produced by the Standard map with no styling at all (the JSON produced is just an empty array).

The closest I can get is the bottom image, using the following (which is not much more than just the default options):

```js
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 26.769528, lng: -82.265607},
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain'],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    fullscreenControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  });
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference? That you (or your customer) cares about?

Comment: @geocodezip - The labels in the top snippets for land masses are italicized and the marker for Reel Intense Inshore Charters is a circle rather than a pointer. As I mentioned, subtle differences but differences none-the-less. I really just find it odd that I can recreate the exact look in the Google Maps Styling Wizard, but it's the default style for the standards map, which I would assume would be the same as what the default JavaScript API provides, but it's clearly not.

Comment: Which version of Maps JavaScript API you load? Note that the tile style changed in release and experimental version, but not in the frozen. Try to add v=3 parameter in your call.

Comment: @xomena - That was it. Thank you.
Edit: Should I delete this question or is this worthy of an answer from you or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@xomena was correct - the tile style has changed in the release and experimental version. Had to use the previous version of 3.31 to match the look.